# What is the role of unconscious in hypnosis?

Tags: hypnosis

[https://www.districthypnosis.com/how-hypnosis-works/#:~:text=The%20U.%20S.%20Government%20defines%20hypnosis,establishment%20of%20acceptable%20selective%20thinking.%E2%80%9D&text=Your%20conscious%20mind%20is%20everything,thought%20and%20your%20analytical%20processes](https://www.districthypnosis.com/how-hypnosis-works/#:%7E:text=The%20U.%20S.%20Government%20defines%20hypnosis,establishment%20of%20acceptable%20selective%20thinking.%E2%80%9D&text=Your%20conscious%20mind%20is%20everything,thought%20and%20your%20analytical%20processes).

The definition of hypnosis as : "*the bypass of the critical factor of the conscious mind and the establishment of acceptable selective thinking.*" suggests that the subconscious plays the main role. But the fact the hypnotized can move, perform the actions suggested shows an unusual power of the es, that in regular sleep is forbidden to it, i.e the control of the body. Has anyone ever discussed, examined and explained this mystery?

This seems to contradict the assertion:"Das Unbewußte kann nichts als wünschen", sagt Freud. [*"The unconscious can only wish"* says Freud.

Comment: Just noting that hypnosis (though not necessarily hypnotherapy) is [generally considered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_topics_characterized_as_pseudoscience#Psychology) pseudoscience, and is therefore off-topic for this forum.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg, it's really odd! hypnotherapy not a pseudoscience which is based on pseudoscience

Comment: Not that odd.  Psychoanalysis is the same, probably many other therapies (Jungian, Gestalt, etc).  It's for the same reason that religious therapy and art therapy being effective treatments does not make religion or art scientific.

Comment: Can you please cite where you saw the text you quoted?

Comment: Related (consious/subconscious/preconscious): https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/992/7604

Comment: Also related (hypnosis): https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/19752/7604

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg, I feel really sorry for those guys who classified it as a pseudoscience, and I wish you might give details on their identity. They seem to ignore the basics of semantics, logic and epistemology. Hypnosis is **not** a theory providing interpretation or prediction ( like astrology etc.), it is a **hard fact**, and as such it is preposterous to call it a pseudoscience. Ala, it is a fact that , ,like acupuncture etc., so-called scientists cannot understand, let alone discuss or explain.

Comment: @user157860 - I am a defender of a lot of "pseudoscientific" theories but if you look at stage hypnosis it is not real hypnosis, so that causes an issue when sceptics look at the scientific validity of hypnosis. For the pseudoscience classification and the "demarcation problem" see my answer at https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2248/7604